# Netlify build causes reading from undefined error vuejs

Tags: vue.js, netlify

I am trying to develop an application in vuejs and deploy it using netlify. Note that I am very new to vuejs. I have no warnings or errors in production but when deploying, the website is blank and the following error appears in console :

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'currentPath')
at index.7d385d0f.js:54:2330
at ls (index.7d385d0f.js:1:23187)
at Proxy.<anonymous> (index.7d385d0f.js:54:2247)
at vn (index.7d385d0f.js:1:15170)
at Jn.b [as fn] (index.7d385d0f.js:1:38048)
at Jn.run (index.7d385d0f.js:1:4525)
at G.c.update (index.7d385d0f.js:1:38314)
at G (index.7d385d0f.js:1:38340)
at rt (index.7d385d0f.js:1:37206)
at ve (index.7d385d0f.js:1:37000)
```

I only use "currentPath" in one file :

In the <script> tag :

```js
export default {
  data: {
    currentPath: "",
  },
  data() {
    return {
      currentPath: window.location.hash || "",
    };
  },
  computed: {
    currentView() {
      return routes[this.currentPath.slice(1) || "/"].route || NotFound;
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    window.addEventListener("hashchange", () => {
      this.currentPath = window.location.hash || "";
    });
  },
};
```

In my html :

```html
<template>
  <notifications />
  <header class="header">
    <a
      v-for="(route, url) in routes"
      :key="route.name"
      class="header-item"
      :class="{ 'header-item-current': this.currentPath === `#${url}` }"
      :href="`#${url}`"
    >
      {{ route.name }}
    </a>
  </header>
  <component class="content" :is="currentView" />
</template>
```

Comment: Ok well I fixed the error by changing this.currentPath to this?.currentPath.
But I still don't understand why I would only have this error once the application is deployed.

Comment: Actually, I fixed the error but then the 'header-item-current' class is not being applied to any element when it should be applied to the element in the header that corresponds to the current page.
This works fine in production.

Comment: You have `data` as an object and as a function on your default export. Remove the object one.  See [data](https://vuejs.org/api/options-state.html#data). You also forgot to mention if you're using Vue2 or Vue3.

Comment: Oh ok, I actually added the object Data in an attempt to solve this problem as I read somewhere that it could be due to the data not being initialized. I am using vue3.

Answer (score 1):

Okay it would seem it is not necessary (and even causes problems) to use 'this.' inside the html of a vuejs SFC.
I have changed

```html
<a
  v-for="(route, url) in routes"
  :key="route.name"
  class="header-item"
  :class="{ 'header-item-current': this.currentPath === `#${url}` }"
  :href="`#${url}`"
>
  {{ route.name }}
</a>
```

to

```html
<a
  v-for="(route, url) in routes"
  :key="route.name"
  class="header-item"
  :class="{ 'header-item-current': currentPath === `#${url}` }"
  :href="`#${url}`"
>
  {{ route.name }}
</a>
```

and not only has the error gone away but everything works fine !